# How do an advanced search for custom content models against an Alfresco repository?

Tags: maven, alfresco, ecm

I have created a custom content model within my Alfresco install using the Alfresco-Maven SDK. I have content in the repository that is stored using my custom type and properties. I have also exposed these types and properties to the advanced search, and I'm able to get results through the share interface...

Now I want to query Alfresco in the same way that I can using share's advanced search, but from an external site running on my PC. I have looked at documentation left and right, but continue just as lost on this topic.

I don't have much experience in web development, much less alfresco. It seems web scripts are the way to go, but I'm not exactly sure how to use them and the examples and tutorials haven't helped me solve this so far.

Comment: Did you try [CMIS](http://cmis.alfresco.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Steps involved to achieve that via webscript

Step1:Create your own webscript.

Step2:Configure webscript to accept all your custom properties as parameter.

Step3:Generate query using these properties in controller of webscript (JAVA or Alfresco javascript).

Step4:Fire query in alfresco repository using alfresco repository services.(Depends on your controlller you can use serachservice for java and search object in javascript).

Step5: Test this webscript in your browser .

Step6: Call same webscript from your other webapplication.

For details on webscripts refer this.

Comment: Did you mean to post a reference somewhere? I'm researching scripts as I can, but I'm still wondering how to get parameters from them.

Comment: To get parameters from script you can use request object.